# Can I use a method or a function as a closure?

Tags: rust

I have some methods on a struct that I'd like to pass around as parameters. I'm pretty sure the only way to pass around functions is by using closures. Is there a way I can do this without doing 
`|| { self.x() }`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can absolutely use a method or a function as a closure. You use the full path to the function or method, including trait methods:

A free function:

```
struct Monster {
    health: u8,
}

fn just_enough_attack(m: Monster) -> u8 {
    m.health + 2
}

fn main() {
    let sully = Some(Monster { health: 42 });
    let health = sully.map(just_enough_attack);
}
```

An *inherent* method:

```
struct Monster {
    health: u8,
}

impl Monster {
    fn health(&self) -> u8 { self.health }
}

fn main() {
    let sully = Some(Monster { health: 42 });
    let health = sully.as_ref().map(Monster::health);
}
```

A trait method:

```
fn main() {
    let name = Some("hello");
    let owned_name = name.map(ToOwned::to_owned);
}
```

Note that the argument type must match exactly, this includes by-reference or by-value.

Comment: Incidentally, trait methods can be specified in a few ways, e.g. `str::to_owned` works (when there's only one `to_owned` on `str` in scope), as does `<str>::to_owned` and `<str as ToOwned>::to_owned`, the latter being the fully qualified form.

Comment: What if the method receiver isn't being passed via the iterator? E.g., `int_iter.map(int_taker.take_int)` (where `takes_int` is a method `fn(&self, I: i64) -> i64` or similar)?