# Easily convert third party Errors to String

Tags: rust

I have this code:

```
fn do_stuff() -> Result<i32, String> {

    let repo = git2::Repository::open(".")?;
    // ...
}
```

This doesn't work because `git2::Repository::open()`'s error type isn't `String`. (Yes I'm being pretty lazy with my error handling by using Strings. It's a tiny program; sue me.)

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::string::String: std::convert::From<git2::Error>` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:94:13
   |
94 |    let repo = Repository::open(".")?;
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::convert::From<git2::Error>` is not implemented for `std::string::String`
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
   = help:   <std::string::String as std::convert::From<&'a str>>
   = help:   <std::string::String as std::convert::From<std::borrow::Cow<'a, str>>>
   = note: required by `std::convert::From::from`
```

I've tried adding this:

```
impl std::convert::From<git2::Error> for String {
    fn from(err: git2::Error) -> Self {
        err.to_string()
    }
}
```

But that isn't allowed because it doesn't reference any types defined in this crate.

I know I can probably use `.map_err()`, but I'd really like it to happen automatically. I kind of feel like I have got this to work before too, which is a bit annoying!

Comment: Yes, you cannot [implement a trait you don't own for a type you don't own](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25413201/155423).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a type implements `std::error::Error`, [it **also** implements `Display`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html):

```
pub trait Error: Debug + Display {
    // ...
}
```

The [`ToString`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/trait.ToString.html) trait, which provides the method `to_string`, is implemented for any type that implements `Display`.

Thus, any type that implements `Error` can be converted to a `String` via `to_string`:

```
use git2; // 0.13.2

fn do_stuff() -> Result<i32, String> {
    let repo = git2::Repository::open(".").map_err(|e| e.to_string())?;
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Comment: How would you fill the `...` in `map_err(...)` with `to_string()` but without the explicit closure `(|e| ...)`? That is, I'm wondering what it would look like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32857265/545794).

Comment: @SeanLeather With Rust 2018 (available at the end of this week in Rust 1.31) you can do `.as_ref().map_err(git2::Error::to_string)`

Comment: @SeanLeather Do [Rust 2018 edition guide](https://rust-lang-nursery.github.io/edition-guide/); [What are non-lexical lifetimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423) help?

Comment: No, unfortunately. It's not clear to me how non-lexical lifetimes allow the change from `.map_err(|e| e.to_string())` to `.as_ref().map_err(git2::Error::to_string)`.

Comment: @SeanLeather they don't, it's just to allow one line, otherwise you'd have to break it down into two lines. `as_ref` is the key to make the value in the `Option` a reference.

Answer (score 3):

Well it turns out there is a bit [in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html#the-real-try-macro) about this. It doesn't allow you to convert to `String`, but apparently all `Error` types can be converted to `Box<Error>` so I just replaced `String` with that. It's cleaner too.

Comment: What's more, `?` and `try!` call `From::from` on their Error argument, meaning that you can use `Box<Error>` and `?` to easily coalesce all sorts of errors into generic error, if that's what you want to do.